# QueryException error while updating data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

Into database not update data, i can't understand my problem, error is below

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22)
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list' (SQL: update `trades` set `_method` = PATCH, `_token` = AcbGEbEyNxX3e2RzRR2cb1SW6NDvkJuDqFevl0Mr, `exchange_id` = 1, `market_id` = 1, `symbol_id` = 45, `is_action` = 0, `tradedate` = , `rate` = 5000, `note` = hhhhhhhhh, `updated_at` = 2018-07-21 13:06:13 where `trades`.`user_id` = 33 and `trades`.`user_id` is not null and `trades`.`deleted_at` is null)

This is my controller

```
 public function edit($id)
{

    $trade = Trade::findOrFail($id);

    $exchanges = Exchange::pluck('exchange','id')->all();
    $markets = Market::pluck('market','id')->all();
    $symbols = Symbol::pluck('symbol','id')->all();
    $reasons = Reason::pluck('reason','id')->all();

    return view('member.add-single-trade.edit', compact('trade','reasons', 'exchanges', 'markets', 'symbols'));
}


public function update(Request $request, $id)
{        
    $input = $request->all();
    $tradeID= Auth::user()->trade($id)->update($input);
    $reasons=$request->input('reason');

    $data = [];
    foreach($reasons as $key => $value) {

        $data[] = ['reason_id' => $value];

    };
                                  $data = array(

                                    'reason_id' =>$reasons,
                                    'trade_id' => $tradeID->id,
                                  );


                                         $test['trade_id']= $tradeID->id;

    if($data > 0) {

        foreach ($data as $datum) {


            $tradeID->tradereason()->update(new TradeReason($datum));

        }
    }

}
```

This is my edit.blade.php file

```
{!! Form::model($trade,['method'=>'PATCH', 'action'=> ['trades\AddSingleTradeController@update',$trade->id]]) !!}


<div class="col-sm-10">

    <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
        {!! Form::label('exchange_id', 'Exchanges:') !!}
        {!! Form::select('exchange_id', [''=>'Choose Options'] + $exchanges , null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
        {!! Form::label('market_id', 'Markets:') !!}
        {!! Form::select('market_id', [''=>'Choose Options'] + $markets, null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-10">
        {!! Form::label('symbol_id', 'Symbols:') !!}
        {!! Form::select('symbol_id', [''=>'Choose Options']+ $symbals   , null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-10">

        {{ Form::radio('is_action', 1) }} Buy
        {{ Form::radio('is_action', 0) }} Sell
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-lg-5">
        {!! Form::label('tradedate', 'Traded date:') !!}
        {!! Form::date('tradedate', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-lg-5">
        {!! Form::label('rate', 'Traded Rate:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('rate', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>


    <div class="form-group col-sm-10">
        {!! Form::label('reason', 'Choose Reasons:') !!}
        {{Form::select('reason',$reasons,null, array('id'=>'reasons','multiple'=>'multiple','name'=>'reason[]',"class"=>"js-example-basic-multiple form-control", 'data-width'=>'60%', 'data-live-search'=>'true','onchange' => 'all_function()'))}}

    </div>


    <div class="form-group col-lg-10">
        {!! Form::label('note', 'Note:') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('note', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'rows' => 2, 'cols' => 40])!!}
    </div>



    <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
        {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class'=>'btn btn-success btn-lg']) !!}
    </div>



    {!! Form::close() !!}




    <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
    {!! Form::open(['method'=>'DELETE', 'action'=> ['trades\AddSingleTradeController@destroy', $trade->id]]) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-lg']) !!}
    </div>

    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is my create.blade.php file

```
<td><a href="{{route('member.add-single-trade.edit', $trade->id)}}">{{$trade->stoploss}}</a></td>
```

Comment: you can simply add the `_method` field to the db or investigate where that field is required. In your code there is no mention for it

Comment: ok i am checking -@DaFois

Comment: Post your model code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't included your model code (probably you are using `$guarded = [];`) but probably instead of

```
$input = $request->all();
```

you should use:

```
$input = $request->except('_method');
```

This is because additional `_method` field is added to form to pass HTTP verb method when using `Form::model` and obviously you don't have `_method` field in your table

**EDIT**

In case you have more fields you can include more fields to ignore for example:

```
$input = $request->except('_method', '_token');
```

or you can only use get fields you really want to get for example:

```
$input = $request->only('exchange_id', 'market_id');
```

(Of course you should add more fields to above - this is only example)

Comment: error is changed `1054 Unknown column '_token' in 'field list' `

Comment: error is :` "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_token' in 'field list' (SQL: update `trades` set `_token` = AcbGEbEyNxX3e2RzRR2cb1SW6NDvkJuDqFevl0Mr, ``

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati Please take a look at my updated answer

Comment: again error: `"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'reason' in 'field list' (SQL: update `trades` set `exchange_id` = 1, `market_id` = 1, `symbol_id` = 45, `is_action` = 0, `tradedate` = , `rate` = 600, `reason` = 3, `note` = hhhhhhhhh, `updated_at` = 2018-07-21 13:26:44 where `trades`.`user_id` = 33 and `trades`.`user_id` is not null and `trades`.`deleted_at` is null) ◀"`

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati Please read carefully my answer. You should exclude (using `except`) or include only some fields (using `only) more fields than I showed. You know your table structure, so fill it in more values after comma and it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$fillable` property of the model to tell ORM which attributes (columns) can be mass assignable. Any other fields passed via update and create methods will be discarded. [check at Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment)